# Consequences of changing a .Net 5 project Sdk

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

## Context

I'm working on a 'plugin-like' system that runs as a windows service. The windows service creates a generic IHost (Let's call this the root Host) which I want to create as web server. The root Host will then look for plugin dll's to load, and it'll create individual IHost's for each plugin (call these child hosts).

Each of these child hosts can run their own kestrel server. I have it set up so that the root host server will act as a reverse proxy to these child host servers. This way only the root host server has to be exposed publicly.

I want to make it so both the root and child host servers can have Api Controllers and serve MVC razor pages.

## My Question

It seems that razor pages cannot be used unless the project Sdk is either `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor`. It also seems like the Windows service project (One that starts the root host) has to specifically be `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` or it wont add the needed application parts.

At the same time though, [Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#worker-service-template) to use the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker` for Worker Service Template's. So I'm wondering what the consequences of using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` sdk for a windows service project are? I assume it causes different MSBuild tasks to be setup, plus different DLL's to be loaded in, but is this stuff that can be done in other ways?

If it's not a good idea to use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, would it be a smarter idea to move all the root host web server stuff to its own project? The windows service project would then just get the IHost from this project and then could go back to being a `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker` project?

### Edit

I ended up going with a restructure of my projects. It's now split up into 3 distinct projects instead of the 2 I originally had.

**Core Project**

The core project is just a standard `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`. It has an extension method for `IHostBuilder` called `ConfigureHostRoot` which adds the `IHostedService`'s needed to look for and load the 'plugins'.

**Http Project**

This project is of the type `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`. It has an extension method for `IHostBuilder` called `ConfigureWebHostProxy` which will add the proxy server. Because this project is the web sdk, it will allow for razor pages to be added.

**Windows Service Project**

I needed a third project to bring those 2 separate parts together. This is the job of the Windows Service. This project is of the type `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker`, and is the only entry point for the entire system.

All it has is the standard `Program.cs` with a `Main()`. All the main does it builds the Host like this:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureHostRoot(integrationBuilder =>
    {
        // Configure the Host root
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostProxy(proxyBuilder =>
    {
        // Configure the reverse proxy
    });
```

Then it'll just build that host and run it for the lifetime of the windows service. Seems like this will work for me, and it means that my core project doesn't have to be a `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` sdk which I like.

I still don't really know if there is any 'downside' to putting it all into the 'core' project and setting it's sdk to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`.

Comment: For web apps that use the Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web SDK, the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting package is referenced implicitly from the shared framework. An explicit package reference in the app's project file isn't required. So, in the web apps (MVC or API), we can create background task. See: [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) and [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-background-task-using-backgrounservice-class-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: For the worker service application, if you change the project SDK from `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker` to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, it will change the project to a web application (without web host), then you could configure the web host. But if you are using the method in the Worker package, it might cause the project broken. So, in my option, I suggest you could directly create a web application, then, configure the background task.

Comment: Is the difference really just different implicit/explicit references? I know Visual Studio doesn't treat them the same. In fact visual studio adding a bunch of extra's (Connected Services, LaunchSettings.json) is the reason I didn't want to use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`.